# density histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

I'm new to R and probability&statistics.  I have a question regarding the histograms...

```
hist(rbinom(10000, 10, 0.1), freq=FALSE)
```

it shows the histogram following diagram which is not clear to me:

[image]

if the y-axis is density, so the total number should be %100, am I wrong?
But in the histogram, I can see that it is bigger than %100.

Answer (score 1):

Function `hist` returns a list object with all information necessary to answer the question.

I will set the RNG seed to make the example reproducible.

```
set.seed(1234)
h <- hist(rbinom(10000, 10, 0.1), freq=FALSE)

str(h)
#List of 6
# $ breaks  : num [1:11] 0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 ...
# $ counts  : int [1:10] 3448 3930 0 1910 0 588 0 112 0 12
# $ density : num [1:10] 0.69 0.786 0 0.382 0 ...
# $ mids    : num [1:10] 0.25 0.75 1.25 1.75 2.25 2.75 3.25 3.75 4.25 4.75
# $ xname   : chr "rbinom(10000, 10, 0.1)"
# $ equidist: logi TRUE
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

The relevant list members are `breaks` and `density`.

1. `breaks` is a vector of length 11, so there are 10 bins.
2. `density` is a vector of length 10, each corresponding to one of the bins.

Now compute the area of each bar by multiplying the bins lengths by the respective densities.

```
diff(h$breaks)    # bins lengths
# [1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
h$density*diff(h$breaks)
# [1] 0.3448 0.3930 0.0000 0.1910 0.0000 0.0588 0.0000 0.0112 0.0000 0.0012
```

Total area:

```
sum(h$density*diff(h$breaks))
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The *area under the curve* should be 1. Since your boxes appear to have width 1/2, the sum of the heights should be 2.   To make this make more sense,  use the `breaks` parameter to `hist`

```
hist(rbinom(10000, 10, 0.1), freq=FALSE, breaks = 5)
```

Or maybe even better

```
hist(rbinom(10000, 10, 0.1), freq=FALSE, breaks=seq(-0.5,5.5,1))
```

[image: Histogram]

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate the density function estimated based on your sample. The answer is approximately 1, so no contradiction.

```
set.seed(444)

s <- rbinom(10000, 10, 0.1)
dens_s <- table(s)/sum(table(s))
sum(as.numeric(names(dens_s))*dens_s)
```